# EE3 and Structure MYSQL Error

Tags: structure

When publishing a page with EE 3.4.7 and  Structure 4.0.0-b.12 we get a SQL error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '15' for key 'PRIMARY':
INSERT INTO exp_structure (site_id, entry_id, parent_id, channel_id, listing_cid, hidden, dead, lft, rgt) VALUES (1,15,0,2,0,'n','', 16, 17)

ee/legacy/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_connection.php:122
```

Havent found a solution yet does anyone have any advice.

Comment: getting some mysqli errors myself too. what if you update structure to the newest version? it just dropped out of beta

Comment: Good call Jelle.

Answer (score 2):

Updating structure out of beta fixed the issue.